How to make a wallpaper centered and not filling the screen?
In all Android phones, whenever we use a picture as a wallpaper, mostly the phone screen is filled with the picture. Moreover, all parts of the picture are not visible.
Please let me know the way so that I can set a picture as wallpaper in the center so that the screen shouldn’t be covered with pictures and all parts of the picture should be visible.

Possibly related: How to set background image without fitting/expanding to fit the screen?

The wallpaper needs to match exactly your screen resolution (display resolution)

Use any app from Play Store that gives you details of your device, for example dev check tells me that display resolution of my Pixel 6a is 2400x1080 (in the display section under hardware)

Copy the wallpaper to your PC and use a photo editing software to crop the image to the exact resolution of screen (be aware that the wall paper may lose some details when you crop, so adjust the crop area suitably). You can search for apps that do cropping on the phone itself. This app claims to do that (not tried by me).

Copy the cropped image to your phone and set it as wall paper


You will have it perfectly centered
